# Facebook OpenGraph custom story attachment

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I am currently trying to implement my own custom story on facebook but i have one problem. I want to create a custom layout for my story but if i click on edit attachment i only get the following two choices:
[image]

I saw some custom layouts on facebook (runstatic) which look similar to what i want to achieve. I found nothing in the docs nor on the web. Anybody an idea?

Comment: These are older layout options, that are not available any more. (Existing apps/stories might still be able to use them, but you can’t create new stories using them.)

Comment: so what can i do to get such a layout like runtastic?

Comment: What part of “not available any more” is unclear …?

Comment: You cant create new ones as highlighted. Out of curiosity what type of story do you want to render ?

Comment: I would love to render first some basic information like a name and date and afterwards a table with 4-6 rows and 3 columns. In this table i would like to display some sports timing information (each round with its time)